# Best way to organize user inputs in a Python class with multiple functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a large class with multiple methods. The first function in the class asks for multiple user inputs and those values are used by multiple other functions in the class.

What would be the best way to 'centralize' these inputs and make them available to all functions within the class? Someone suggested to me that I should put those inputs as Class parameters so the user could see how many inputs are needed, as currently the user would not know if they will need to input two parameters or two hundred.

```
class Simulation:
    
    def pull_data(self):

        input1 = input()
        input2 = input()
        input3 = input()

    def simulate(self, input1, input2, input3)
```

Also what happens if my user inputs aren't always fixed, so for example imagine that the user first inputs a selection and then the subsequent inputs will depend on that. If they chose option a, then one set of inputs will be asked for, otherwise another set of inputs will be asked for. Could I still 'centralize' these all of the inputs even though half of them will never be used? For example

```
class Simulation:
    
    def pull_data(self):

        input1 = input()
        if input1 == 'bla':
            input2 = input()
            input3 = input()
        
        else:
            input2 = input() # these inputs are different questions to the above
            input3 = input() 

    def simulate(self, input1, input2, input3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the inputs as attributes to `self`.

```py
class Simulation:
    
    def pull_data(self):

        self.input1 = input()
        self.input2 = input()
        self.input3 = input()
```

Now, you can refer to the inputs in any function in the class using `self.input1`, `self.input2`, and `self.input3`.

Check the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp) for `self`